# Why am I getting segmentation fault or double free detected with dynamic ptr arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, segmentation-fault

UPDATE: Retired Ninja if you ever read this thank you so much! getting rid of "Todo" for the second array fixed everything! I have been trying to fix this for like 8 hours lol I seriously cannot thank you enough!!

So I'm making a program that creates a ToDo list and I keep getting a segmentation error for my first array being too small but in the code I deleted it and made it bigger already.

Also if I just make the array a bigger number to fix it temporarily I start to get a double free detected in tcache 2 error.

Any solutions or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Note: I would much prefer to use a vector but for this assignment a dynamic array is required.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Date
{
    public:
    
    Date()
    {
        time_t currentdate = time(0);
        tm* date = localtime(&currentdate);
        cout << "Today's date: " << 1 + date->tm_mon << "/" << date->tm_mday << "/" << 1900 + date->tm_year << endl << endl; // For some reason my system month was only 10 so I had to add 1
    }
};

class Todo
{
    public: 
        string todoItem, addDate;
        int itemID;
        
        
        
    void setData(string input, int arraysize)
    {
        input.erase(0,1);
        todoItem=input;
        itemID=arraysize;
        stringstream buffer;
        time_t currentdate = time(0);
        tm* date = localtime(&currentdate);
        buffer << "Date added: " << 1 + date->tm_mon << "/" << date->tm_mday << "/" << 1900 + date->tm_year << endl << endl;    
        addDate = buffer.str();
    }
    
    void getData()
    {
        cout <<"GetData:\n";
        cout << itemID << "/" << todoItem << "/" << addDate << endl;
    }
};

void ProgramGreeting();
char MenuChoice(string todoItem);

int main()
{
    ProgramGreeting();
    bool menuloop=true;
    bool firstrun=true;

    
    string input;
    int arraysize=1;
    int arrayindex=arraysize-1;
    
    // in the array below I can put an arbitrary number so it wont get the segmentation fault but then I get the double free error instead
    Todo *todoptr = new Todo[arraysize]; 
    
    do{
        getline(cin,input);
        switch (MenuChoice(input))
        {
            case '+':
            
                cout << "plus loop\n"; //program runs this last line of code then crashes with double free error
                if (firstrun==false)
                {
                    
                    arrayindex=arraysize-1;
                    Todo *tempptr = new Todo[arraysize];
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayindex; i++)
                    {
                        tempptr[i]=todoptr[i];
                    }
                    //tempptr++;
                    tempptr[arrayindex].setData(input, arraysize);
                    //tempptr--;
                    delete[] todoptr;
                    Todo *todoptr = new Todo[arraysize+1];
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
                    {
                        todoptr[i]=tempptr[i];
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
                    {
                        todoptr[i].getData();
                    }
                    
                }
                if (firstrun==true)
                {
                    todoptr->setData(input, arraysize);
                    firstrun=false;
                }
                arraysize++;
                break;
            case '-':
            
                break;
            case '?':
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid entry. If you would like to quit, enter 'Q'";
                string quit;
                cin >> quit;
                if (quit=="q" or quit=="Q")
                    {
                        menuloop=false;
                    }
                break;
        }
    } while(menuloop==true);
}

void ProgramGreeting()
{
    cout << "Hello and welcome to my to do list maker!\n"
            "Program Author: John Doe\n";
            Date date;
            cout << endl;
            
}

char MenuChoice(string input)
{
    int n=input.length();
    char charray[n+1];
    strcpy(charray, input.c_str());
    return charray[0];
}
```

Comment: This snippet won't compile. Please make a [mre]

Comment: Btw, why not use a `std::vector<Todo>` instead of using `new` to do the dynamic allocation manually?

Comment: This deletes the pointer declared outside the loop: `delete[] todoptr;` This declares a new variable with the same name that shadows the one outside: `Todo *todoptr = new Todo[arraysize+1];` Everything before that line in the loop refers to the outside `todoptr` and everything after that line to the end of the loop refers to the new variable. You most likely just want `todoptr = new Todo[arraysize+1];` inside the loop, otherwise the second iteration tries to delete the same pointer for the second time.

Comment: Note that the code is not standard C++. `char charray[n + 1];` is a variable length array. Don't use them. Use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` instead.

Comment: The `MenuChoice` function is completely unnecessary. `switch (input[0])` is the same thing. Should have a check for `!input.empty()` first in both cases as well.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.  Fix the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

there are many errors that make it crash.
for examples:

Variable shadowing: there are two "Todo *todoptr", that's why double free happend.  "outer todoptr" dont't has a valid pointer when enter the third '+'.

assginment in for loop maybe out of range